# cycle in a dataframe with dates and between dates in python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, cycle

I would like to process all the data between two dates changing the dates. In particular, I have the following dataframe:

```
                   real    model2      model1
date                                               
2017-01-01 00:00:00   51.22   52.776425   52.583711
2017-01-01 01:00:00   53.00   47.211506   50.679937
2017-01-01 02:00:00   52.00   44.722529   48.478772
2017-01-01 03:00:00   51.00   42.475170   45.141708
2017-01-01 04:00:00   47.27   38.862827   44.583250
2017-01-01 05:00:00   45.49   39.473972   44.930338
2017-01-01 06:00:00   45.69   42.465659   47.380179
```

where dates are also indexes. 
I would like to collect all the data day by day in a list to pass to a function. I have done it in a not smart\correct way as:

```
for iday in range(1,9):
   #
   #
   start_date = '2017-01-0'+str(iday)+ ' 00:00:00'
   end_date   = '2017-01-0'+str(iday)+ ' 23:00:00'
   #
   data_sub_e = EE.loc[start_date:end_date]
```

It sounds not correct, it is difficult to extend to a number of day greater then 10 and it seems to not use pandas feature.

Is there any smart way to do that?

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Comment: whats wrong with `df.loc[(df['date'] >= 'your_date') & (df['date'] <= 'your_date')]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that *date* is of *datetime* type (not *string*).

Using *df.index.date* you can select rows by the **date part only**.

E.g.:

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')  # The criterion date
df[df.index.date == d1]   # Get all rows from this date, whatever the hour part
```

**Another hint**: Instead of your loop based on the day number:

```
for iday in range(1,9):
```

run a loop based on *pd.date_range*, something like:

```
for dat in pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-01-15', freq='D'):
```

Of course, set the end date according to your needs.

**Another choice** can be to group your DataFrame by the date part of
the index:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))
```

and then apply your function to each group.

## Edit following the comment

To change your values into lists, for each group, you can use
*named aggregation*:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).agg({'real': list,
    'model1': list, 'model2': list})
```

If you want to assign own column names, you can use another syntax,
with named parameters:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).agg(Real=('real', list),
    Model_1=('model1', list), Model_2=('model2', list))
```

Here parameter names specify output column names. The value of each
parameter is a tuple: (*original column name*, *aggregation function*).

Comment: I like the first one: date part only. However, it is not clear how I can move to a list all the value with that date.  Another possibility could be  pd.date_range ans pass the value with a cycle?